# Getting StackOverFlowError and unsure why?

Tags: java, class, methods, stack-overflow, extends

The program I am trying to create is a basic game where the user inputs a grid size the selects blocks receiving either a prize which adds to the score, a bandit which takes points away from the score or a bomb to end the game. I am getting a stack flow error and i can not figure out why?

Sorry for the large amounts of code I am just unable to find the problem!

This is the stack overflow error I'm receiving. It happens after you enter the grid size(It is much longer then this as you can see gameItems, blockHop, and prize keep repeating continuously :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.System.nanoTime(Native Method)
at java.util.Random.<init>(Random.java:62)
at BlockHop.<init>(BlockHop.java:12)
at GameItems.<init>(GameItems.java:20)
at Prize.<init>(Prize.java:9)
at BlockHop.<init>(BlockHop.java:27)
at GameItems.<init>(GameItems.java:20)
at Prize.<init>(Prize.java:9)
at BlockHop.<init>(BlockHop.java:27)
at GameItems.<init>(GameItems.java:20)
at Prize.<init>(Prize.java:9)
at BlockHop.<init>(BlockHop.java:27)
at GameItems.<init>(GameItems.java:20)
```

Block Hop GUI:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BlockHopGUI extends JFrame{

  private BlockHop bh;
  private JButton [][] board;
  private JLabel scorePoints;
  private PlayHandler ph;  // listener for buttons

  public BlockHopGUI( int gridSize ) {
    super( "Click to uncover prizes" );
    bh = new BlockHop( gridSize );
    System.out.println( "gridsize: " + gridSize );
    Container c = getContentPane( );
    JPanel p = new JPanel( );
    board = new JButton[gridSize][gridSize];
    p.setLayout( new GridLayout( gridSize, gridSize ) );

    ph = new PlayHandler( );
    for ( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ )
      for ( int col = 0; col < board.length; col++ ) {
      board[row][col] = new JButton( "" );
      board[row][col].addActionListener(ph);
      p.add( board[row][col] );
    }
    c.add( p, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel( );
    JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel( "Score: " );
    scorePoints = new JLabel( Integer.toString( bh.getScore( ) ) );
    scorePanel.add( scoreLabel );
    scorePanel.add( scorePoints );

    c.add( scorePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    setSize( 500, 500 );
    setVisible( true );  
  }

  private class PlayHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
      for ( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ ) 
        for ( int col = 0; col < board[0].length; col++ ) {
        if ( ae.getSource( ) == board[row][col] ) {
         bh.play( row, col );
         board[row][col].setText( bh.getLabel( row, col ) );
         board[row][col].removeActionListener( ph );
         break;
        }
      }
      scorePoints.setText(  Integer.toString( bh.getScore( ) ) );
      if ( bh.isGameOver( ) ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Game over! Final points: " 
                                    + bh.getScore( ) );
        System.exit( 1 );   
      }
```

Block Hop Class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BlockHop {

  Random rand = new Random();
  private GameItems [] [] board;
  int score = 100;
  int row;
  int col;

  public BlockHop () {
    board = new GameItems [1][1];
    board[0][0] =  new Prize( 0, 0, 'P') ;
  }

  public BlockHop( int gridSize )  {
    board = new GameItems [gridSize][gridSize];
    int end = 10;
    int start = 1;
       for ( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ )
        for ( int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++ ) {

    int numAssign = rand.nextInt( end - start + 1 ) + start;
       // System.out.print("test");
       switch (numAssign) {
      case 1: case 2 : case 3 : case 4 : case 5 : case 6 :
        board[row][col] =  new Prize( row, col, 'P') ;
        System.out.print("test");
        break;
      case 7:
        board[row][col] = ( new Bomb( row, col, 'B') );
        System.out.print("test");
        break;
    case 8: case 9 : case 10 :
        board[row][col] = ( new Bandit( row, col, 'X') );
        System.out.print("test");
        break;
    }
   }

  }

  public void  play( int row, int col )  {
  String newID = getLabel(row, col);
   //newID.adjustScore()

  }


   public int getScore( ) {

    return score;
  }



  public String getLabel(int row, int col) {
   if ((board[row][col]).equals('P'))
     return "p";
   else if ((board[row][col]).equals('X'))
     return "x";
   else
     return "b";

  }

  public boolean isGameOver( ) {
    if ( getScore() < 0)
      return true;
    else
   return false; 
  }



}
```

Game Item Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public abstract class GameItems extends BlockHop {

  private char ID;  // block type
  private int row;      // row 
  private int col;      // column


  public GameItems (){
    ID = ' ';
    row = 0;
    col = 0;
  }

  public GameItems (int newRow, int newCol, char newId) {
    row = newRow;
    col = newCol;
    ID = newId;


  }

  public int adjustScore(char input) {
    switch (input) {
      case 'P' :
     score += 10;
     break;
      case 'X':
     score -= 5;
     break;
      case 'B' :
     score -= 2000;
     break;

  }
    return score;

    }
    }
```

Prize Class:

```
public class Prize extends GameItems{
  public Prize () {
    super();
  }

  public Prize (int row, int col, char id) {
    super (row, col, id);
  }
}
```

Bomb Class:

```
public class Bomb extends GameItems {
  public Bomb () {
    super();
  }

  public Bomb (int row, int col, char id) {
    super (row, col, id);
  }
}
```

Bandit class:

```
public class Bandit extends GameItems {
  public Bandit () {
    super();
  }

  public Bandit (int row, int col, char id) {
    super (row, col, id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't see the problem from the code provided. When does the StackOverFlow happen? Does it happen when you click on any button on the board or when you click on multiple buttons and keep clicking away?

Comment: It happens after you enter the grid size

Comment: `gridSize` is too large

Comment: You notice a pattern there?  The problem is you keep drilling deeper and deeper and never make any progress.  This is because you ask for a Prize in the BlockHop constructor, and Prize is a GameItems which is a BlockHop.  So the constructor repeatedly calls itself.

Comment: right but what do i do to change this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a stack overflow in the constructor..

In `BlockHop` you have:

```
  public BlockHop () {

    board = new GameItems [1][1]; 
    prize = new Prize(...);
  }
```

However you have `GameItems` defined as:

```
public abstract class GameItems extends BlockHop {
//...
}
```

Every time you construct an instance of a class that inherits from `GameItems`, it constructs a `BlockHop` which constructs a `Prize` which inherits `GameItems`.. Why? because:

```
public class Prize extends GameItems {
//...
}
```

So now every time you construct a Prize, it constructs a block hop and vice versa.

Comment: Ah sorry for the late reply, was taking a nap. Here's the thing, don't make `GameItems` extend `BlockHop` just to access the score. Instead, make score static and add a setter for it. Remove the extension from `GameItems` and use the setter or make it `public and static`.. Example: http://ideone.com/o8pN2q

Comment: Note my comment is just a suggestion and is just a quick fix. You should really revise your need for inheritance and figure out what you really want to do. There are many topics on `Inheritance vs. Composition` and when to use static variables.

Comment: right thanks i did that and it worked but when i run the program every  time i click a box its a bomb and the score doesn't adjust

Comment: No where in your code on the OP do you adjust the score though. The function is written but isn't called/used. You need to use it to `adjust` your score.

Comment: but this wont fix the bomb from coming up everytime?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47911/discussion-between-user2985542-and-cantchooseusernames)

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflowError itself telling you what is wrong with the program, If you see these lines which are making a pattern

```
at Prize.<init>(Prize.java:9)
at BlockHop.<init>(BlockHop.java:27)
at GameItems.<init>(GameItems.java:20)
```

If you check these lines. all these are happening at time of object creation of these classes which clearly says that `for creation of GameItems you need BlackHop creation` and `for BlackHop you need Prize Creation` and `for Prize you need GameItems creation`. And this is due to your inheritance hierarchy. Hence the Stack Overflow Error happening.

Comment: right thanks but how do i fix this? i've been fiddling around and i'm getting no where

Comment: You'll need to fix the class relationship. Why does GameItems extends BlockHop? What are you trying to achieve by having GameItems extends BlockHop?

Comment: i need it to extends BlockHop for the variable score?

Comment: What you can do is, instead of using inheritance, you can use composition. that means GameItems holds a reference to BlokHop and then you can use score by using getter/setter on BlockHop instance. hope this solves your issue